# Creating Open extension by extensionName creates extension with id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have used graphexplorer v1.0 to create/update/delete open extensions which seem to keep an extensionName atribute that you can reference them by. Fine.

However, when I mimic this POST via my UWP app then the resulting open extension no longer has an extensionName but instead has some random id: ?

This leads to 404 when i subsequently try to update with the original extensionname https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/extensions/com.mycompany.myExtn ?

Am I missing something or is the documentation out of date?
Do I store this GUID for future reference?

thanks
Phil.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my mistake - I was not posting the @odata.type and extensionName properties corectly in the payload ;-(